# Parent category is showing products in subcategories, even though product was not assigned to parent category

Tags: catalog, category, indexing, ce-1.4.0.1

Let's assume I have a category, Clothing and this category have a sub-category, T-shirts.

Now I add a product to the T-shirts category (by checking the box in the add product screen), but I don't check the Clothing category. So, I assumed this meant that the product would only appear in the T-shirts category on the front end, and not in the  parent category Clothing.

However, the product appears in the Clothing and T-shirt categories.

This is a problem because the T-shirt category is an "Include in navigation menu" > No category, i.e. It is supposed to be hidden. All the products in the category have visibility of catalog, so they don't appear in search results.

I've investigated this quite deeply so far and have found that the problem is with the Magento catalog indexing. Running the Category Products indexer from **System > Index Management** rebuilds the index, running `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Indexer_Product::reindexAll()`.

This function SELECTs various data from several category-related tables and pipes it into the catalog_category_product_index table, which is the table used to generate the products collection for the category pages.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to hide/prevent products from sub-categories appearing in their parent categories?

I'm using Magento 1.4.1.0. The Clothing category is set to Anchor and the T-shirts category is not. Use flat category is set to yes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is actually a feature. If you want to avoid this you should set the flag 'Is anchor' to 'No' on the parent category. In your example 'Clothing'. This way, in the parent category you will see only products directly assigned to it.
After you do the changes you should re-index everything.

Comment: Ahh, but I need to keep "Is Anchor" on the parent category, because it uses Layered Navigation.

Comment: Erm....then I think you have a problem. I'm out of ideas on this.

Comment: I don't need the layered navigation in the T-shirts category, so I think I'll move the T-shirts category out of Clothing, so it will only show directly related products as you say

Comment: @sfrost2004 So, T-shirts are not clothing? I guess I've been using them wrong...

Comment: @Marius Still no ideas on this one? Exclude products from parent category while keeping layered navigation.

Comment: @Marius We have a similar problem. Suppose we would solve this in code. Is it possible to distinguish the "real/actual" category products from the "anchor" added products?? (is there a flag "comes from lower in the tree" or "anchor product" ... this way we could filter out the one or the other

Comment: @snh_nl. I don't think there is such a flag.

Comment: hmmm I was looking @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990622/magento-stop-child-products-showing-in-anchor-category where I saw $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor'] = 1; AND maybe something tlink this $this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('is_parent', array('eq' => 1)) -- If it is a parent

Comment: @Marius In my case, all my products assigned with subcategories and child categories, for bulk report parent category only convenient to get reports. Here how can i assign all products to the parent category by programmatically. Thanks.

Comment: @Marius how we can avoid filter option values of sub categories in parent layered navigation ?

Comment: Hi, has anyone found the solution? I want to hide the product from the parent category without removing the layered navigation and show the product only in the child category.