# Magento2 : Parent category load child category's product too

Tags: magento2, category, products

In my store parent category load collection of its child category also.
I can solve it by **Is Anchor** to "**No**".
But by doing this Filter is not coming in the left bar so it is not the solution of my problem.
How can I load the products which I assigned to the category itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this for Magento 1. You can see the answer [in here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/179045/146).
You can try a similar approach in M2. Not sure it will work, though.
The anchor flag is taken into consideration in the `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::addCategoryFilter()` method.

Maybe it will work with an `around` plugin, where you set the anchor to 0, then execute the initial method and set it back to the value it was before.

Something like this (untested):

```
public function aroundAddCategoryFilter(
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $subject,
   callable $proceed,
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
) {
    //remember the category anchor flag
    $anchor = $category->getIsAnchor(); 
    //set anchor to 0.
    $category->setIsAnchor(0);
    //execute the original method and remember the result
    $result = $proceed($category);
    //set back the anchor flag on the category
    $category->setIsAnchor($anchor);
    //return what the original method returned;
    return $result;
}
```

More info about creating a plugin in the [official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Comment: It filter the products but not made changes in left side filter.It show all attributes of child category's products too,and wrong product count including child category.

Comment: I have achieved filter products by changing _applyProductLimitations() function. Do you have any idea for Filter?.Anyway thanks for help it better than my solution

Comment: Thanks @Marius..